# Cannot find the DialogWorkItemDetails method when reflecting the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls assembly

Tags: c#, tfs

I am attempting to utilize an existing Dialog within the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls assembly that will show the details of a TFS Work item that is sent. I am utilizing reflection to do this, in a similar manner found to [accessing the DialogChangesetDetails method used here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10063064/).

However, after creating the assembly, array object to store the method arguments, the DialogChangesetDetails method cannot be found using the .CreateInstance method:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (WorkItemPolicy));
            var args = new object[] {this, workItem, false};
            using (
                var dialog =
                    (Form)
                        assembly.CreateInstance(
                            "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogWorkItemDetails", false,
                            BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, args,
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null))
            {
                if (dialog == null) return;
                dialog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                dialog.ShowDialog();
            }
```

In order to ensure that I was not attempting to reach the method in a wrongful manner, I used a reflector to receive information about it:

```
public DialogWorkItemDetails(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window parent, WorkItem workItem, bool allowModification)
    {
        this.m_workItem = workItem;
        this.m_allowModification = allowModification;
        this.m_workItemStartedOutModified = this.m_workItem.IsDirty;
        this.InitializeWindow();
        this.UpdateButtons();
        this.GetWorkItemDetails();
        new WpfDialogAssistant(this)
        {
            HelpTopic = "vs.tfc.sourcecontrol.DialogWorkItemDetails"
        }.SetOwner(parent.Handle);
    }
```

As far as I can see, I am sending the method the correct parameters, including the form parent, work item and whether the user can modify the work item.

You can find the [entire DialogWorkItemDetails reflected code here](http://pastebin.com/n9TAY9ps).

Comment: I just looked through the reflected code some more. DialogChangesetDetails' constructor is internal, while DialogWorkItemDetails is public. Should that make a difference when using reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that since I was trying to access a Public method, I should not have been using BindingFlag.NonPublic. I updated it, and had to change my cast since the Dialog is not a disposable form.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (WorkItemPolicy));
var args = new object[] {this, workItem, true};
var dialog =
    (Window)
        assembly.CreateInstance(
            "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogWorkItemDetails", false,
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, args,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

            if (dialog == null) return;
            dialog.ShowDialog();
```